# How to do a bash `for` loop in terraform termplatefile?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-ssm

I'm trying to include a bash script in an AWS SSM Document, via the Terraform `templatefile` function. In the `aws:runShellScript` section of the SSM document, I have a Bash for loop with an `@` sign that seems to be creating an error during `terraform validate`.

Version of terraform: 0.13.5

Inside `main.tf` file:

```
resource "aws_ssm_document" "magical_document" {
  name              = "magical_ssm_doc"
  document_type     = "Command"
  document_format   = "YAML"
  target_type       = "/AWS::EC2::Instance"
  content           = templatefile(
    "${path.module}/ssm-doc.yml",
    {
      Foo: var.foo
    }
  )
}
```

Inside my `ssm-doc.yaml` file, I loop through an array:

```
for i in "$\{arr[@]\}"; do
  if test -f "$i" ; then
    echo "[monitor://$i]" >> $f
    echo "disabled=0" >> $f
    echo "index=$INDEX" >> $f
  fi
done
```

**Error**:

> **Error: Error in function call**
>
> Call to function "templatefile" failed:
> ./ssm-doc.yml:1,18-19: Invalid character;
> This character is not used within the language., and 1 other diagnostic(s).

I tried escaping the `@` symbol, like `\@`, but it didn't help. How do I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the error is pointing to the `@` symbol as being the cause of the error, it's the `${ }` that's causing the problem, because this is Terraform interpolation syntax, and it applies to templatefiles too. [As the docs say](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html):

> The template syntax is the same as for string templates in the main Terraform language, including interpolation sequences delimited with `${ ... }`.

And the way [to escape interpolation syntax in Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html) is with a double dollar sign.

```
for i in "$${arr[@]}"; do
  if test -f "$i" ; then
    echo "[monitor://$i]" >> $f
    echo "disabled=0" >> $f
    echo "index=$INDEX" >> $f
  fi
done
```

The interpolation syntax is useful with `templatefile` if you're trying to pass in an argument, such as, in the question `Foo`. This argument could be accessed within the `yaml` file as `${Foo}`.

By the way, although [this article didn't give the answer](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-use-templatefile-to-pass-a-powershell-script-into-commandtoexecute/17916/2) to this exact issue, it helped me get a deeper appreciation for all the work Terraform is doing to handle different languages via the `templatefile` function. It had some cool tricks for doing replacements to escape for different scenarios.

Comment: As an aside, `>>$f` over and over is somewhat inefficient -- you're opening the file before each `echo` and closing it when that `echo` completes. Consider putting the contents of the `if` inside a block: `{ echo foo; echo bar; echo baz; } >>"$f"` opens the output file only once and redirects all three `echo`s into it.